# Sticky keys in tiling window manager

Tags: window-manager, i3-wm, keys, tiling

what is the best tiling window manager that supports sticky keys?
I learned I3, but unfortunately it doesn't support sticky keys and I didn't find any applications to install on I3 that supports sticky keys to work both in parallel.